# preventing UITableView from calling numberOfRowsAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In my `UITableViewCell` subclass I have a `UITableView`, the question is that whenever I scroll the table view the UITableView, the numberOfRowsAtIndexPath, cellForRowAtIndexPath, is getting called all the time. how do I prevent this from happening aside from hiding it while scrolling?

Comment: these are required methods to load a uitableview

Comment: datasource methods would definitely be called.

Comment: You cannot prevent them from calling, these are datasource methods required for displaying cell.

Comment: There's no such thing as `numberOfRowsAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Your -numberOfRowsAtIndexPath: shouldn't be getting called more than about once or twice. It shouldn't be called whenever you scroll.

On the other hand, -cellForRowAtIndexPath: will get called very often when you scroll. It will get called each time just before a new cell appears. This is just the normal behavior, and you wouldn't want to prevent it if you could.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you scroll the table, it will reload its cells. To provide data to those cell's it will call datasource methods. You can not prevent it. First try to understand the basic concepts of UITableView.

Comment: It will only call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,  not `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSections`. These are only called once.

Answer (score 0):

in the uitableview delegate method is call always.

if your dont want means you cant load your data into your table cell.

otherwise you may check inside the no.of row and cell for row at inexpath function

if tableview is not scrolling means return count; and set cell content